# Playing audio via bluetooth speaker for Pi3 (Stretch)

Tags: raspbian, audio, bluetooth, raspbian-stretch

This is the oft repeated question on playing audio via bluetooth on RPi. There are too many posts out there, but most of them are dated or do not apply to the stretch version of raspbian and hence asking this question again.

I am on RPiv3 Model B with Raspbian stretch. I am able to connect to my bluetooth speakers successfully. When i try to play something to it using OMXPlayer or MPG123, there is no error, but i cannot hear any sound. I have checked to ensure that the speaker is working properly by connecting from my mobile. Also, when i play via headphone jack it seems to play properly.

Both OMXPlayer and mpg123 seem to diregard the `-o alsa` command to run on bluetooth. I have tried various options and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens with me. It's basically trial and error. First off, you need to turn off Bluetooth  (if you have it on). Then turn on the Bluetooth speaker, and turn on Bluetooth on the RPi. At the top right corner, right click and choose your Bluetooth device. It should connect. Try playing some sound. What you basically have to do is always turn on Bluetooth on the speaker first, then the RPi.